# Java - list of subdirectories and files within a path + size?

Tags: java, file, size, directory

For example, if I have a directory on my computer, c:\test that contains the following
directories and files:

C:\test\foo\a.dat (100kb)

C:\test\foo\b.dat (200kb)

C:\test\foo\another_dir\jim.dat (500kb)

C:\test\bar\ball.jpg (5kb)

C:\test\bar\sam\sam1.jpg (100kb)

C:\test\bar\sam\sam2.jpg (300kb)

C:\test\somefile.dat (700kb)

Running the command java ClassName c:\test I want to have the output like that, sorting by size from largest to smallest ?:

DIR C:\TEST\FOO 800KB

FILE C:\TEST\SOMEFILE.DAT 700KB

DIR C:\TEST\BAR 405KB

```
Path startPath = Paths.get("C:\\test");
Files.walkFileTree(startPath, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
@Override
public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
    System.out.println("Dir: " + dir.toString() + " "+getFolderSize(path()));
return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}

@Override
public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
System.out.println("File: " + file.toString());    
return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}

@Override
public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException e) {
return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}
});

} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

so far I got this part which can produce the output of all of the files and directories (which is not what I want) and without the size ? anybody with a help what to do next ?

THX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this (output in bytes):

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileSearcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File f = new File("C:\\test");
        FileSearcher.search(f);
    }

    public static void search(File f) {
        if(null == f) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.print("| " + f.getAbsolutePath());
        if(f.isFile()) {
            System.out.print(" (" +  f.length() + ")");
        } else if(f.isDirectory()) {
            File[] children = f.listFiles();
            if(null != children) {
                for(File c : children) {
                    search(c);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Oh and if you happen to care about the human-friendly file sizes, something like this will convert them for you (just change f.length() to friendlyFileSize(f.length()):

```
public static String friendlyFileSize(long size) {
    String unit = "bytes";
    if(size > 1024) {
        size = size / 1024; 
        unit = "kb";
    }

    if(size > 1024) {
        size = size / 1024; 
        unit = "mb";
    }

    if(size > 1024) {
        size = size / 1024; 
        unit = "gb";
    }
    return size + " " + unit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution sorts the results by size from largest to smallest using the format 
`<file-path> (<file-size>kb)`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

class du { 
    static class Pair {
        private String path;
        private Long size;
        public Pair(String path, Long size) { 
            this.path = path;
            this.size = size;
        }
        public String getPath() {
            return path;
        }
        public Long getSize() {
            return size;
        }
    }

    private static void diskUsage(File file, List<Pair> results) throws IOException {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            String[] subFolderPaths = file.list();
            for (String path : subFolderPaths) { 
                diskUsage(new File(path), results);
            }
        } else {
            results.add(new Pair(file.getAbsolutePath(), file.length()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Usage: du <folder-path>");
        }
        File folder = new File(args[0]);
        if (folder.isDirectory()) {
            List<Pair> results = new ArrayList<du.Pair>();
            diskUsage(folder, results);

            Collections.sort(results, new Comparator<Pair>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Pair o1, Pair o2) {
                    return Long.compare(o2.getSize(), o1.getSize());
                }
            }); 

            for (Pair p : results) { 
                System.out.printf("%s (%dkb)\n", p.getPath(), p.getSize() / 1024);    
            }
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%s (%dkb)\n", folder.getAbsolutePath(), folder.length() / 1024);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each file in folder and call `file.size()` to get the size of file in bytes. Keep summing it up and you will have the entire folder size.

For sorting, you can keep the file-name and size in a HashMap and then use a custom comparator to sort out the entire dictionary using `Collections.sort`

Answer (score 0):

```
   import  java.io.File;
   import  java.util.ArrayList;
   import  java.util.Collection;
   import  java.util.Iterator;
   import  java.util.List;
   import  java.util.TreeMap;
   import  org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
/**
   <P>java SizeOrderAllFilesInDirXmpl</P>
 **/
public class SizeOrderAllFilesInDirXmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
      File fDir = (new File("R:\\code\\xbn\\"));
      Collection<File> cllf = FileUtils.listFiles(fDir, (new String[]{"java"}), true);

      //Add all files to a Map, keyed by size.
      //It's actually a map of lists-of-files, to
      //allow multiple files that happen to have the
      //same length.

      TreeMap<Long,List<File>> tmFilesBySize = new TreeMap<Long,List<File>>();
      Iterator<File> itrf = cllf.iterator();
      while(itrf.hasNext())  {
         File f = itrf.next();
         Long LLen = f.length();
         if(!tmFilesBySize.containsKey(LLen))  {
            ArrayList<File> alf = new ArrayList<File>();
            alf.add(f);
            tmFilesBySize.put(LLen, alf);
         }  else  {
            tmFilesBySize.get(LLen).add(f);
         }
      }

      //Iterate backwards by key through the map. For each
      //List<File>, iterate through the files, printing out
      //its size and path.

      ArrayList<Long> alSize = new ArrayList<Long>(tmFilesBySize.keySet());
      for(int i=alSize.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)  {
         itrf = tmFilesBySize.get(alSize.get(i)).iterator();
         while(itrf.hasNext())  {
            File f = itrf.next();
            System.out.println(f.length() + ": " + f.getPath());
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
44271: R:\code\xbn\number\vx\XIFLengthInRange.java
39318: R:\code\xbn\text\ConsecutiveDups.java
34747: R:\code\xbn\z\iw\list\ify\IWListify.java
32224: R:\code\xbn\array\NonPArrayFromPrimitiveUtil.java
32130: R:\code\xbn\list\ify\earray\NewListifyPableArray.java
31842: R:\code\xbn\array\WrapperArrayUtil.java
30142: R:\code\xbn\text\regex\RegexReplacer.java
30129: R:\code\xbn\list\ListUtil.java
29116: R:\code\xbn\xcfu\XCFUCmdLineParams.java
27940: R:\code\xbn\array\helper\NewPrimitiveArrayHelper.java
27417: R:\code\xbn\z\iw\java\util\IWCollection.java
26807: R:\code\xbn\text\ProcessEscapedECs.java
...and so on...
```